# Group action inverse?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

> Suppose  $G$ acts on $\Omega.$ It's easy to see that if $g \in G$ is arbitrary, then the function $\sigma_g: \Omega \to \Omega$ defined by $(\alpha)\sigma_g = \alpha \cdot g$ has an inverse: the function $\sigma_{g^{-1}}$. Therefore, $\sigma_g$ is a permutation of the set $\Omega$, which means $\sigma_g$ is both injective and surjective, and thus $\sigma_g$ lies on the symmetric group $\text{Sym}(\Omega)$ consisting of all permutations of of $\Omega$. [...]

My question is what's the function $\sigma_{g^{-1}}$? Is it the function  $\sigma_{g^{-1}}: \Omega \to \Omega$ defined by $$(\alpha)\sigma_{g^{-1}} = \alpha \cdot g^{-1}$$

In which case we would have $\alpha \sigma_g \alpha \sigma_{g^{-1}} = \alpha g \alpha g^{-1}$ which doesn't seem to be the identity. I think I'm being confused by the notation.

The only way this would make sense to me is that if I define $\sigma_{g^{-1}}: \Omega \to \Omega$ by $$\sigma_{g^{-1}} = (\alpha \cdot g)^{-1} = g^{-1}\alpha^{-1}.$$

But that does not appear to be consistent with the author's notation.

Comment: Where is the quote from? Please [edit] the question to include it.

Comment: The issue is confusing the function f with its value f(x). To see if g is the inverse of f, you have to compose f and g, not f(x) and g(x).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\sigma$ is a function. So it only makes sense for function composition. Then $(\alpha)(\sigma_g \circ \sigma_{g^{-1}}) = (\alpha \cdot g)\cdot g^{-1} = \alpha$.